# QScroll bar range not setting properly

Tags: qt, qscrollarea

I am trying to set the QScrollbar range using QScrollBar::setrange(min, max). But the values are not reflected when the app is run.

This is the code called from MainWindow constructor.

```
ui->setupUi(this);
    QScrollArea* scroll = new QScrollArea(this);
    scroll->setGeometry(ui->frame->geometry());
    scroll->setWidget(ui->frame);
    scroll->verticalScrollBar()->setRange(0, 1000);
    qDebug() << "Max is " << scroll->verticalScrollBar()->maximum();
    scroll->show();
```

PFA the images
[image: App]

[image: Designer]
Am I missing something. Any leads would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd guess `QScrollArea::show` recalculates the range based on the size of the widget. You could try to call `setRange` after `show`, but what are you trying to achieve anyway?

Comment: The [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractscrollarea.html#details) of `QAbstractScrollArea` shows an example on how to set the `pageStep` and `Range`. Maybe that helps.

Comment: @KarstenKoop I want to set the scrollbar range based on some calculation, instead of the size of the scrollArea content. Based on the current value of the scroll, I have to load the content inside the scroll area.. And I tried setting range after show is called.. Even that didnt help

Comment: @JeffreyvandeGlind Tried setting the pagestep and min-max, in some button click event.                                                                      valuesscrollArea->verticalScrollBar()->setMinimum(0);
    scrollArea->verticalScrollBar()->setPageStep(768);
    scrollArea->verticalScrollBar()->setMaximum(2560); I can see the scroll bar size is changing as per the new values, but going back to original values(which QScrollArea calculated from its contents size) immediately.. Is anything missing..?